# How to make dynamic size strings

Tags: c

So I started h0mbre's C course on github and I can't do the dinamic strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *first, *last;

    printf("What is your first name?\n");
    scanf("%ms", &first);
    printf("And what is your last name?\n");
    scanf("%ms", &last);

    printf("Hello, %c %c!\n", first, last);

    free(first);
    free(last);

    return 0;
}
```

After I input my first name, the program just spits some random characters and this is the Output:

```
What is your firs name? 
Antonio 
And what is your last name? 
Hello, ► ð!
```

Comment: `%ms` does not look standard to me

Comment: Enable more verbose compiler warnings, and it should point out the errors.

Comment: @GovindParmar It's a POSIX extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `%s` to scan and print strings in C.
A string in C is an array of `char`, so you must allocate memory dinamically for it.
You can also use `char first[50]` without dinamic allocation with `malloc`.
If you use `malloc` you must always check the return value of it, same thing with `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 50

int main(void)
{
    char *first, *last;
    if((first = malloc(DIM*sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find free memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((last = malloc(DIM*sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find free memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("What is your first name?\n");
    if (scanf("%s", first) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in scanf");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("And what is your last name?\n");
    if (scanf("%s", last) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in scanf");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Hello, %s %s!\n", first, last);
    free(first);
    free(last);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `%s` to print c-strings:

```
printf("Hello, %s %s!\n", first, last);
```

As noted in coAlso be aware that `%ms` is not part of C but a [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html).

> The %c, %s, and %[ conversion specifiers shall accept an optional
> assignment-allocation character 'm', which shall cause a memory buffer
> to be allocated to hold the string converted including a terminating
> null character. In such a case, the argument corresponding to the
> conversion specifier should be a reference to a pointer variable that
> will receive a pointer to the allocated buffer. The system shall
> allocate a buffer as if malloc() had been called. The application
> shall be responsible for freeing the memory after usage. If there is
> insufficient memory to allocate a buffer, the function shall set errno
> to [ENOMEM] and a conversion error shall result. If the function
> returns EOF, any memory successfully allocated for parameters using
> assignment-allocation character 'm' by this call shall be freed before
> the function returns.